# impossible to launch android application with intelij

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

when i try to launch an android application with intelij i got this error

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\Intelij Project\DistanceShutdown

AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33\n\nThis Android Gradle plugin (7.0.4) was tested up to compileSdk = 31\n\nThis warning can be suppressed by adding\n    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33\nto this project's gradle.properties\n\nThe build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to\nuse a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33","sources":[{}]}

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingTriggerDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugResources
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":444,"endLine":9,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":548}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml:9:5-10:11: AAPT: error: resource dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":25,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":2173,"endLine":27,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":2427}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:26:5-28:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":28,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":2432,"endLine":30,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":2698}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:29:5-31:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml","position":{"startLine":6,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":427,"endLine":8,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":621}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:7:5-9:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml","position":{"startLine":9,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":626,"endLine":11,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":834}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:10:5-12:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\legam.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml:9:5-10:11: AAPT: error: resource dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical) not found.

```
 ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:26:5-28:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush) not found.
     
 ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:29:5-31:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush) not found.
     
 ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:7:5-9:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu) not found.
     
 ERROR:C:\Users\legam\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f61097c849c6ff4e003885f716fc82af\transformed\material-1.8.0\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:10:5-12:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu (aka fr.plaglefleau.distanceshutdown:style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu.ContextMenu) not found.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 32s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date

Hope that someone can help and thanks in advance

I try to redownload gradle and that didn't work and i also try to change gradle version